# Long word exceeding column in lyx

Tags: lyx, margins, minipage

I have a long text that exceeds the column margins

It's not an English word. it's this hexadecimal number

172CB875A0C7A7868CBCB9AEF80F97392560559ADF1D107FBD3EBFE56802D1990DDF842E15E308D7441041CE93F65971D2F71C4A442DA9440000000000000460

How to fit it the column?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  is your concern the input or the output?  if output, an approach for dna strings is addressed in [How to break long words after n chars (long genomic sequences)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116441/579).

Comment: Consider using a fixed width for the column. Does that help?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, your suggestion worked. Kindly answer the question so that I can accept it.

Comment: the convention of this site is to close a question that has a duplicate or an answer to another question that is directly applicable to the current question.  so instead of answering, i've voted to close.  but this is a very good question, so please don't hesitate to ask if you encounter another problem for which an answer isn't obvious.