# Hyphenation anywhere

Tags: hyphenation

Is there a (simple) way to allow hypheation a-n-y-w-h-e-r-e in any word?

Comment: not exactly what you've asked for, but maybe helpful: [How to break long words after n chars (long genomic sequences)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116441/579)

Comment: I guess you could set `\lefthyphenmin=1` and `\righthyphenmin=1` in the preamble. Be forewarned: The typographic results are likely to be awful.

Comment: @Mico Setting `\lefthyphenmin=1` and `\righthyphenmin=1` wouldn't be enough, because the hyphenation patterns still wouldn't allow hyphenations like `anyw-here` or `anywh-ere` AFAIK (which are consistent even with the TeX defaults of `\lefthyphenmin=2` and `\righthyphenmin=3`).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - You are right. In fact, according to the comment the OP left below @Jfbu's answer, he/she does *not* want to change the default values of `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin`; put differently, hyphenation should in fact not literally be allowed `a-n-y-w-h-e-r-e` in any word. I must confess that since the use case for the query was never particularly clear to me, I hadn't given it much additional thought. Do you think I should delete my comment?

Comment: @Mico No please don't delete it; it's fine. Also, the comment below the answer was left not by the OP but by me, earlier today. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `xelatex` this is easily done.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
% "texdoc xetex" for Xe(La)TeX reference manual
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate 1
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 0 = {\-}
\begin{multicols}{5}
  \kant[42]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: hyphenation everywhere]

In contrast the output without the use of `\XeTeXinterchartoks`:

[image: standard hyphenation]

Perhaps you even don't want the `-`'s. Then the following can be used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
% "texdoc xetex" for Xe(La)TeX reference manual
{% temporarily enable hyphenation everywhere at no cost
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate 1
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 0 = {\discretionary{}{}{}}
\exhyphenpenalty 0
\begin{multicols}{5}
  \kant[42]
\end{multicols}
}

% back to normal
\end{document}
```

[image: no hyphens]

Or possibly you prefer the `-` to stick into the right margins:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
% "texdoc xetex" for Xe(La)TeX reference manual
{% temporarily enable breaking everywhere
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate 1
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 0 = {\discretionary{\rlap{-}}{}{}}
\exhyphenpenalty 0
\hyphenpenalty   0
\begin{multicols}{5}
  \kant[42]
\end{multicols}
}

% back to normal
\end{document}
```

[image: with hyphens in margin]

Comment: Is it possible to do this while still respecting `\lefthyphenmin=2` and `\righthyphenmin=3`? That is, `an-ywhere`, `any-where`, `anyw-here`, `anywh-ere` would all be allowed, but not `a-nywhere` or `anywhe-re` or `anywher-e` (In particular, words shorter than 5 characters wouldn't be hyphenated)?

Comment: @user4686 Your answer is very helpful. If I use it, but replace \kant[42] with a string of characters in scriptio continua (for example, ``ΑΜΕΝΑΡΤΑΣΤΟΥΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΥΓΕΝΟΥΣΤΟΥΑΙΓΥΠΤΙΟΥΗΤΟΥΚΑΛΛΙΚΡΑΤΟΥΣΙΣΙΔΟ...''), then the characters tend to be somewhat lax about obeying the right margin of each column. Do you know a fix?