# Text going past page

Tags: formatting, text, wrap, page

I want it to automatically wrap paragraphs around the page just like other text editors like microsoft word. Is there any way to do this? maybe something I can add in the premable?

here's my code for reference:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{subsection test}
dfsjklkljfdsjkldfshjkfhjkfdgsahfhdjks;;fdhsfh;fsdhfdshjfdshhjhffhlsjdkalhjfksfsdlhjkfsldhjkfhlsjlfhdjsaklfhjksfdshjlkfhjdklsfdhskjlafsdhkljakfhjlsd

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Add some spaces in your text and you will get linebreaks ...

Comment: If you are willing to put the long text in a command then you can use something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/wrapping-long-lines-that-contain-no-spaces.

Comment: And when using XeLaTeX you could use something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275093/hyphenation-anywhere to allow breaks without the need for a command around the text, with the option to either print a hyphen at a line break or don't print anything and just continue on the next line (second code block in the answer).

Comment: You might also look at the url package.