# Allow break anywhere with no hyphenation in a listings in-line command

Tags: listings

Here, I use the function `\txtbrut` to write in typewritter font certains things such as file names or functions in python, matlab, etc. I use `listings` for the colouring of the code and because it does a better job at cutting names than `\texttt`. But it is not at a 100% reliable, and I do not need here the same convention as for normal text.

How could I modify my function `\txtbrut` so it allows break anywhere, with no hyphenation ?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hmargin=8cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand*{\txtbrut}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]}%[

\begin{document}

\txtbrut{Iletaitunefoisunejeuneetjolieprincessequiaimaiteclaterlecranedesesennemis.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: does this help? [How to break long words after n chars (long genomic sequences)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116441)

Comment: @barbara beeton To some extent, yes this looks like a useful package. Although not featured in the MWE, I would prefer a solution that uses listings for the coloured code. Also, `\seqsplit` is not in `\texttt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I compare the OP's `\txtbrut` to an alternate `\alttxtbrut`.  The `\alttxtbrut` code was adapted from one of egreg's answer's as an alternative to the `\url` macro, as I recall (maybe someone could provide a link).  Even so, one may still be required to place the paragraph in a `sloppypar` to get the margins just so.

Now if non-alphanumeric characters are needed (I am not sure of the syntax requirements of the languages he/she mentions), adjustments would be necessary.

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hmargin=8cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand*{\txtbrut}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]}%
\newcommand\alttxtbrut[1]{\tbhelp#1\relax\relax\relax}
\def\tbhelp#1#2\relax{%
  {\texttt{#1}}\penalty0\ifx\relax#2\else\tbhelp#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}

\txtbrut{Iletaitunefoisunejeuneetjolieprincessequiaimaiteclaterlecranedesesennemis.txt}

\begin{sloppypar}% <--MAY BE NEEDED
 \alttxtbrut{Iletaitunefoisunejeuneetjolieprincessequiaimaiteclaterlecranedesesennemis.txt}
This is the text that follows.
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It works quite good, but indeed I use this as a verbatim environment to be able to insert special characters (well, mainly underscores). Is there a way to adapt your code to take these into account ?

Comment: @HcN Yes, in the `\tbhelp` macro, change `\texttt{#1}` to `\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}`.  That will still not be able to handle `%` in the input and will break if unmatched braces are in the input.

Comment: Ok this works now. I have a final request, it seems like it cannot cope with spaces. Is there a fix for that ? also, it is a bit of a shame that it does not use the `listings` package (so I will have to find another solution to have my code in colour), but this does the trick for what I need.

Comment: @HcN Brute force fix is to include space within braces in the argument: `\alttxtbrut{Iletai_t_un{ }efoisunejeuneetjolie.txt}`