# latex csvreader table wrap cells with long strings

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I am using csvreader to import a csv file and display it as a table. The first column contains strings that are very long and so the column takes up most of the page, meaning the table continues off the page. Is there a way to force a cell value to continue on the next line? I don't mind if it is hyphenated  or not, but it would be great if I could specify a max length for the first column and the strings wrap if they are too long. Example code below:

```
    \documentclass{report}

    \usepackage{csvsimple}

    \begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
    LongString,ColA,ColB,ColC
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMABCDEFGHIJKLMABCDEFGHIJKLMABCDEFGHIJKLM,12345,23456,34567
    NOPQRSTUVWXYZNOPQRSTUVWXYZNOPQRSTUVWXYZNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,45678,56789,67890
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \csvreader[
        tabular=|c|c|c|c|,
        column count=4,
        table head=\hline,
        table foot=\hline,
        no head,
        late after first line=\\\hline,
        respect all
    ]{test.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: `seqsplit` as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310923/134144 in combination with a `p` type column might be helpful.

Comment: That solution requires me to surround each value with \seqsplit{}. As the data comes from a csv file I cannot do that.

Comment: I cannot even run your example. I tried with `pdflatex` on an updated TeXLive2019 installation, and get errors. How am I supposed to compile it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [csvsimple wrap table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574845/csvsimple-wrap-table-cells)