# Break long word (not long text!) in longtable cell

Tags: line-breaking

How to break VERY long word in latex? For example:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{8cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 & 2  & 3 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 overlaps next table cells in it's row. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Turns out that seqsplit doesn't work for me, as it removes existing spaces between words. I forgot to mention that text may contain space and I didn't notice that it eliminates spaces :(

Comment: welcome to tex.se! you should use `babel` for used language. if word hasn't defined hyphenation, you should insert them manually (with `\-`). as you show in code fragment, you haven't real word, so the meaning of series of digits with this can change its meaning. be careful with hyphenation in such a cases.

Comment: This isn't exactly the same situation but the long string that needs to be broken isn't a word: [How to break long words after n chars (long genomic sequences)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116441)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Many thanks for mentioning the `seqsplit` appoach; I've updated my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(updated the answer to mention the `seqsplit` approach)

I have two suggestions:

- load the `xurl` package and encase the very long "word" in an `\url` directive, and
- load the `seqsplit` package and encase the very long "word" in a `\seqsplit` directive.

[image]

It looks like the `\seqsplit` approach manages to pack its contents a tad more tightly than the `\url` approach does.

In the following code, I replaced `longtable` with `tabular` since the example isn't really specific to the `longtable` package and its machinery.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl,seqsplit,array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % optional
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & C \\ 
\hline
\urlstyle{same}% default is '\urlstyle{tt}'
\url{11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111} & 2  & 3 \\ 
\seqsplit{11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111}
& 2  & 3 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\seqsplit` will most likely use the main font, while `\url` may use a monospace font; that could account for the difference in packing density.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. My answer made sure to include the directive `\urlstyle{same}`; the font *should" be the same in both cells.

Answer (score 3):

One can do manual breaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{8cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\-11111111111111 & 2  & 3 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: also with use of `tabular` can be to wide  (OP not provide any information about its document layout)...   use of the `longtable` has sense, if the table can not be placed on one page ... OP question is not very clear :-(

Comment: @Zarko Yes, `longtable` or `tabular` can't fix the too-wide issue. But this particular table is not long enough (but I know the main table the OP is working on is longer :))

Comment: how you know this? apparently  you have crystal ball :-). mine is out of order :-(.

Comment: @Mico Yes forgot that. Thanks

Comment: @Zarko Hmm I have none. I just take the OP's code and put `\-` to a random position in the `1111111111111111...` Or am I misunderstanding the word "crystal ball"?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do manual breaking, as long as I generate latex document for automatic invoice.

Comment: @GeorgyFarniev I can't consider `\-` as time-consuming. Just put a single `\-`. I don't believe your "word" goes to three lines.

Comment: @JouelV, again, I do not create document manually, I generate it from input data, let's say, received by API. seqsplit package solved my problem.

Comment: @GeorgyFarniev Alright no problem