# Text in longtable cells not wrapping correctly

Tags: longtable, minipage

I'm trying to generate a LaTeX jinja template for a table split over multiple pages which will be populated with automatically generated LaTeX. To achieve this, I use the `longtable` environment, however, when a cell contains a word with too many characters, it is not correctly wrapped. Here is the relevant snippet of code for the table (with dummy content):

```
\def\arraystretch{1.2}

\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{p{0.1\linewidth} p{0.2\linewidth}  p{0.7\linewidth} }
  \# & question & answer \\
  \arrayrulecolor{brand_dark} \hline
  \endhead
  
  \rowcolor{brand_light} \multicolumn{3}{l}{tXRcRDxdKJOJHbSAAZeOCcoEPlpNzymLx} \\
  \rowcolor{white}
  LRenA &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft}KMtMfYwfHkGLLbaZFAfRtTFj\end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage} & \hspace{0pt}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth - 0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
      udrPJNdJGqOLzgGJjs
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}

  \\
  
  \rowcolor{light-grey}
  ZCKhv &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft}hnjtmbuJPwyvBkbGjKJMEojGlUHREvvzwKwSSQeOEU\end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage} & \hspace{0pt}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth - 0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
      NmEwyZowJszdELsNktHfOvSaSNmIqIDHqabyKtNzuUgReEauJpiwjppdQWrHqorhMBgopxsROQEHPs
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}

  \\
  \rowcolor{white}
  DPzyJ &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft}ikHnifxdnsPJNGEqvwTWjvHZ\end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage} & \hspace{0pt}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth - 0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
      BRiTGeOBvY
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}

  \\
  
  \rowcolor{light-grey}
  LYYiI &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft}ALdgFWrSKqcNpBEeDvtnZX\end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage} & \hspace{0pt}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth - 0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
      UtyYPYhXSSmSUzgnO
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}

  \\
  \rowcolor{white}
  plBsz &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{flushleft}VckBeukgwVihwVXtYbAPqgzd\end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage} & \hspace{0pt}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth - 0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
      VTEQmsYvTjinhubaqZDqVXSEdtmZVpwuYlLAIWGQbQmcRLnfhISiIdIpmhEEbGPMqoWCroWOHqJuMvCCEgtWqganBlBoJomZLvQQpSArshkAUXscRwLUyWbslXqMmEgUgdLvxnGnNcvMZgnRii
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}

\end{longtable}
  
\end{document}
```

The results in the following table:

[image: longtable with incorrectly wrapped cells]

Not that the content of the middle and right-most cells is encapsulated
in a mini page as in general, it can contain newlines as well as arbitrarily nested `itemize`, `enumerate`, `flushleft`, `flushright` and `center` environments and uses of `\emph`, `\textbf` and `\color`.

What would be the best way of making this sort of text wrap correctly?

Comment: If it were actual words in the cells, there would also be proper line breaks. So, maybe what you are really looking for is just [a way how to break long strings anywhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116441/47927)?

Comment: Off-topic: Since you load `xcolor` with the option `table`, the instruction `\usepackage{colortbl}` is redundant.

Comment: @Mico Thank you, I've removed it :)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, most of the time these boxes will be filled with natural language, however, there can be long URLs, italicised and bolded text, as well as itemize and enumerate environments that do not seem to work with any of these solutions...

Comment: you have posted a lot of code but almost none of it is related to your issue which is is that `hnjtmbuJPwyvBkbGjKJMEojGlUHREvvzwKwSSQeOEU` does not line break using English hyphenation patterns.  You could have just posted a paragraph with these strings without any table or packages in the example which would have made it much easier for people to provide a focussed example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes indeed, my apologies, I've edited the post, leaving only the relevant snippet I think. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with the `longtable`, beside the fact that the linebreaks aren't very good. For one, the overall width of the `longtable` is currently exceeds `\textwidth` by `6\tabcolsep`, or about half an inch/more than a centimeter.

To force line breaks in long strings to occur at the end of each line (and, in the process, to suspend ordinary hyphenation rules which might otherwise kick in), I suggest you load the `seqsplit` package and employ its `\seqsplit` macro where needed.

The fact that the long strings may or may not occur inside `minipage`, `center`, `flushright`, etc environments does not imply that you couldn't use `\seqsplit` directives if and where needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
%%%\usepackage{colortbl} % rendundant
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{everypage} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Comfortaa-Bold}

\usepackage[landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{light-grey}{RGB}{243, 243, 243}
\definecolor{brand_dark}{RGB}{28, 69, 135}
\definecolor{brand_light}{RGB}{201, 218, 248}

\newcommand{\Company}{Company}
\newcommand{\CompanyURL}{company.com}
\newcommand{\Index}{QA}

\newcommand{\monthyear}{\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or %
  April\or May \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or %
  December\fi, \number \year} 

% Turn on the style
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Clear the header and footer
% \fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% Set the right side of the footer to be the page number
\fancyfoot[R]{\color{brand_dark}Page \thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\color{brand_dark}{\monthyear}}

\AddEverypageHook{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[brand_dark] (current page.north west) rectangle ($ (current page header area.north -| current page.east) + (0,0.5) $);
\node [above right = 0.5cm and -2cm of current page header area.north west] {\color{white} \Company \; | \, \Index \, 2021 };
\node [above left = 0.6cm and -2cm of current page header area.north east] {\color{white} \CompanyURL};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\def\arraystretch{1.2}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan}

% new:
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ P{0.1} P{0.2} P{0.7} }

  \# & question & answer \\
  \arrayrulecolor{brand_dark} 
  \hline
  \endhead

  \hline
  \endlastfoot
 
  \rowcolor{brand_light} 
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{tXRcRDxdKJOJHbSAAZeOCcoEPlpNzymLx} \\[0.1ex]

  \rowcolor{white}
  LRenA &
  \seqsplit{KMtMfYwfHkGLLbaZFAfRtTFj} &
  udrPJNdJGqOLzgGJjs \\
  
  \rowcolor{light-grey}
  ZCKhv &
  \seqsplit{hnjtmbuJPwyvBkbGjKJMEojGlUHREvvzwKwSSQeOEU} & 
  \seqsplit{NmEwyZowJszdELsNktHfOvSaSNmIqIDHqabyKtNzuUgReEauJpiwjppdQWrHqorhMBgopxsROQEHPs} \\

  \rowcolor{white}
  DPzyJ &
  \seqsplit{ikHnifxdnsPJNGEqvwTWjvHZ} & 
  BRiTGeOBvY  \\
  
  \rowcolor{light-grey}
  LYYiI &
  \seqsplit{ALdgFWrSKqcNpBEeDvtnZX} & 
  UtyYPYhXSSmSUzgnO \\

  \rowcolor{white}
  plBsz &
  \seqsplit{VckBeukgwVihwVXtYbAPqgzd} & 
  \seqsplit{VTEQmsYvTjinhubaqZDqVXSEdtmZVpwuYlLAIWGQbQmcRLnfhISiIdIpmhEEbGPMqoWCroWOHqJuMvCCEgtWqganBlBoJomZLvQQpSArshkAUXscRwLUyWbslXqMmEgUgdLvxnGnNcvMZgnRii}  

\end{longtable}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: "Second, the use of minipage environments seems unnecessary; " Unfortunately I don't think it is, this is intended as a template, with dummy information filling it, but the cells can, in general, contain itemize or enumerate environments, which of course contain line breaks. They can also contain bolded and italicized tests using the \textbf and \em macros, which also does not seem to render correctly when seqsplit is applied.

Comment: @JulianSutherland - I think it would a good idea if you edited your query to provide more information about what exactly may end up in the cells. Incidentally, I'm still not convinced that one needs `minipage` wrappers to encase `enumerate` and `itemize` environments in `p`-type columns. Since your code loads the `enumitem` package, one can set up bespoke variants of `itemize` and `enumerate` environments that embed themselves transparently in `minipage` environments. Without more specific information about what may be in the cells, thoughit's not possibly to be more specific.

Comment: I've edited the post appropriately. I want to be able to nest `enumerate` and `itemize` environments arbitrarily, as well as top level newlines and use the macros `\textbf`, `\emph` and `\color`. Could you point me towards information on how to setup these bespoke variants of `itemize` and `enumerate` with the `enumitem` package? Thank you very much.

Comment: I forgot I want to be able to nest `flushleft`, `flushright` and `center` environments to adjust the alignment of nested paragraphs.

Comment: @JulianSutherland, than please show us, how you nest this environment so far, and whyt is in this environments. Also please make your document example minimal (from preamble remove all what is not related to problem with your table). So far your question is not entirely clear.

Comment: @JulianSutherland - The best I can tell from your update, the fact that you may need long strings to line-break in arbitrary ways is merely one of several, possibly interrelated but so-far-not-entirely-clear formatting needs. That said, the presence of possibly nested `minipage`, `enumerate`, `itemize`, etc environments does not detract from the fact that `\seqsplit` should allow line breaks in long strings. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mico Yes I agree, thank you very much, I've accepted your answer, algorithmically, it's a little annoying to have to wrap every word of sufficient length with `\seqsplit`, but it can be done! :)

Also thank you very much for pointing me in the direction of eliminating minipages. It seems to be possible to do almost everything I want to do without them, and I think they were responsible for adding inappropriate spacing.

Answer (score 0):

As suplement to nice @Mico answer (+1). Just to show, that his solution enables to use lists in table. For formatting of lists is sensible to define new lists types adopted for use in (any) tables with prescribed columns widths (as you can find in many answers regarding lists in tables):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Comfortaa-Bold}

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{light-grey}{RGB}{243, 243, 243}
    \definecolor{brand_dark}{RGB}{28, 69, 135}
    \definecolor{brand_light}{RGB}{201, 218, 248}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}% <-- defined new enumerate list
    \setlist[tabenum]{nosep,
                      label*=\textbf{\arabic*.},
                      leftmargin=*,
                      before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}%
                                    \vspace*{-0.6\baselineskip},% <---
                      after=\end{minipage}}

    \newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new itemize list
    \setlist[tabitem]{nosep,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     label=\textbullet,
                     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},    % <---
                     after=\end{minipage}                       % <---
                     }
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,
                    positioning}
% new:
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\newcommand{\Company}{Company}
\newcommand{\CompanyURL}{company.com}
\newcommand{\Index}{QA}

\newcommand{\monthyear}{\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or %
  April\or May \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or %
  December\fi, \number \year}

% Turn on the style
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Clear the header and footer
% \fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% Set the right side of the footer to be the page number
\fancyfoot[R]{\color{brand_dark}Page \thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\color{brand_dark}{\monthyear}}
\AddEverypageHook{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[brand_dark] (current page.north west) rectangle ($ (current page header area.north -| current page.east) + (0,0.5) $);
\node [above right = 0.5cm and -2cm of current page header area.north west] {\color{white} \Company \; | \, \Index \, 2021 };
\node [above left = 0.6cm and -2cm of current page header area.north east] {\color{white} \CompanyURL};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ P{0.1} P{0.2} P{0.7} }
  \# & question & answer \\
  \arrayrulecolor{brand_dark}
  \hline
\endhead
  \hline
\endlastfoot
% table body
  \rowcolor{brand_light}
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{tXRcRDxdKJOJHbSAAZeOCcoEPlpNzymLx} \\[0.1ex]

  \rowcolor{white}
  LRenA &
  \seqsplit{KMtMfYwfHkGLLbaZFAfRtTFj} &
  udrPJNdJGqOLzgGJjs \\

  \rowcolor{light-grey}
  ZCKhv &
  \seqsplit{hnjtmbuJPwyvBkbGjKJMEojGlUHREvvzwKwSSQeOEU} &
  \seqsplit{NmEwyZowJszdELsNktHfOvSaSNmIqIDHqabyKtNzuUgReEauJpiwjppdQWrHqorhMBgopxsROQEHPs} \\

  \rowcolor{white}
  DPzyJ &
  \seqsplit{ikHnifxdnsPJNGEqvwTWjvHZ} &
  BRiTGeOBvY  \\

  \rowcolor{light-grey}
  LYYiI &
  \seqsplit{ALdgFWrSKqcNpBEeDvtnZX} &
  UtyYPYhXSSmSUzgnO \\

  \rowcolor{white}
  plBsz &
  \seqsplit{VckBeukgwVihwVXtYbAPqgzd} &
  \seqsplit{VTEQmsYvTjinhubaqZDqVXSEdtmZVpwuYlLAIWGQbQmcRLnfhISiIdIpmhEEbGPMqoWCroWOHqJuMvCCEgtWqganBlBoJomZLvQQpSArshkAUXscRwLUyWbslXqMmEgUgdLvxnGnNcvMZgnRii}\\

  \rowcolor{light-grey}
  Item itemize  &
  \begin{tabitem}
  \item \seqsplit{ALdgFWrSKqcNpBEeDvtnZX}
  \item \seqsplit{ikHnifxdnsPJNGEqvwTWjvHZ}
  \end{tabitem} &
  UtyYPYhXSSmSUzgnO \\

  \rowcolor{white}
  Item itemize + enumerate  &
  some text before list
  \begin{tabitem}
  \item \seqsplit{ALdgFWrSKqcNpBEeDvtnZX}
  \item \seqsplit{ikHnifxdnsPJNGEqvwTWjvHZ}
  \end{tabitem} &
  \begin{tabenum}
  \item \seqsplit{VTEQmsYvTjinhubaqZDqVXSEdtmZVpwuYlLAIWGQbQmcRLnfhISiIdIpmhEEbGPMqoWCroWOHqJuMvCCEgtWqganBlBoJomZLvQQpSArshkAUXscRwLUyWbslXqMmEgUgdLvxnGnNcvMZgnRii}
  \item \seqsplit{ikHnifxdnsPJNGEqvwTWjvHZALdgFWrSKqcNpBEeDvtnZX}
  \end{tabenum}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]